# How to generate normally distributed random numbers in specific interval?

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

I want to generate 100 normally distributed random number in interval [-50,50]. However in the below code the range of random number generated is [-50,50].

```
n <- rnorm(100, -50,50)
plot(n)
```

Comment: A random number from the normal distribution can't have boundaries as it is random around a mean and the probability to have a number far from the mean decreased with distance but is never null

Comment: you can never guarantee that all your sampled numbers are within that range if you sample from a normal distribution. You can only say you want, for instance, 95% of your sampled numbers to be in that range. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: You could research the truncated normal distribution, although generating random numbers without having a clear probability model in mind can lead to meaningless results. Don't use a truncated normal unless you are convinced that it is a good fit for whatever it is that you are trying to model.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is atrangely asked, because it seems you don't fully understand the `rnorm` function.

```
rnorm(100, -50,50)
```

generates a sample of 100 points given by a normal distribution centered on -50, with a standard deviation of 50. So you need to specifiy what you want by :
`100 normally distributed random number in interval [-50,50]`. In a normal distribution you don't give an upper and lower limit : the probability of drawing is never 0, but is just very low when being several standard deviation away from the mean. So:

- Or you want a normal distribution centered on 0 with 50 standard deviation, and the answer is `rnorm(100, 0,50)`, but you will have values above 50 and below -50.
- Or you actually want a normal distribution with no value outside the [-50,50] range, and in this case you still need to give a standard deviation, and you will need to cut the values draw outside the range. You could do something like:

  `sd <- 50
  n <- data.frame(draw = rnorm(1000, 0,sd))
  final <- sample(n$draw[!with(n, draw > 50 | draw < -50)],100)`

Here is an example of what it does for 2 different `sd`:

```
sd <- 10
n1 <- data.frame(draw = rnorm(1000, 0,sd))
final1 <- sample(n$draw[!with(n, draw > 50 | draw < -50)],100)
sd <- 50
n2 <- data.frame(draw = rnorm(1000, 0,sd))
final2 <- sample(n$draw[!with(n, draw > 50 | draw < -50)],100)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
hist(final1,main = "sd = 10")
hist(final2,main = "sd = 50")
```

[image]

- or you just want to sample values in this range with a flat distribution. In this case, just `sample(-50:50,100,replace = T)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a sacrifice. Either your random variable is not normally distributed because the tails are cut off, or you compromise on the boundaries. You can define your random variable to "practically" lie in a range, this is you accept that a very small percentage lies outside. Maybe 1 % would be an acceptable choice for your purpose.

```
my_range <- setNames(c(-50, 50), c("lower", "upper"))
prob <- 0.01 # probability to lie outside of my_range
# you have to define this, 1 % in this case
my <- mean(my_range)
z_value <- qnorm(prob/2)
sigma <- (my - my_range["lower"]) / (-1 * z_value)

# proof
N <- 100000 # large number
sim_vec <- rnorm(N, my, sigma)
chk <- 1 - length(sim_vec[sim_vec >= my_range["lower"] & 
                            sim_vec <= my_range["upper"]]) / length(sim_vec) 
cat("simulated proportion outside range:", chk, "\n")
```